# Bending a bar with a torus attached to one end

Tags: constraints

I'm an absolute beginner with Blender (5 days so far) and I'm hoping someone can help me.
I'm trying to bend a flat bar with a torus attached to one end.
I used the bend feature in the "simple deform" modifier for bending the bar and attached a torus to one of its ends using the "Child OF" constraint. the problem I'm having is that the torus doesn't stay flat against the bar as it bends (Please see attached images 1 through 4).
Please help!!!
Thanks in advance
[image: Image-1]

[image: Image-2]

[image: Image-3]

[image: Image-4]

Comment: is this for an animation?

Comment: You atached the torus to verts, but the verts don't have rotation data, only location, so the torus isn't supposed to rotate. If you want to solve it this way, you have to use a track to constraint too, what makes the torus look at the Empty at the origo.

Comment: FFeller..... Thanks soooo much, ill try that.
susu........ yes, it is for animation, thanks.